# Testing Webflow with rich context

Tags: unit-testing, spring-webflow

Can Webflow be tested within Spring's @WebAppConfiguration so I don't have to create mock service beans etc?

In particular, the webflow's (terse) [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/testing.html) on testing makes no notice of this and suggests testing with stub classes for services. This might work for very granular unit tests but not for integration tests or more incremental unit tests.

Comment: NOTE: I actually just found the answer to this and thought I would share as it i not documented anywhere to my knowledge. If this is a faux pas, a high rep person can let me know and I will delete

Answer (score 0):

Even though not documented, it does work and it can be useful. Use Spring's @WebAppConfiguration and use webflow to register services.  Note that the services will not be invoked just because they are found by the @WebAppConfiguration. They need to be registered in the webflow test as well.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

/**Use @WebAppConfiguration with path specified from maven's root to webapp root. 
 * Extend AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests as per Webflow's documentation***/
@WebAppConfiguration("/WebContent")
@ContextHierarchy(
{ @ContextConfiguration(locations =
    { "classpath:AssessmentAdminTL-servlet.xml" }) })
public class TestFlowTest extends AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests
{

@Autowired
private BusinessService businessService;

@Autowired
private AdminUserViewService adminUserViewService;

@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

/**Specify flow config location***/
@Override
protected FlowDefinitionResource getResource(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory)
{
    return resourceFactory.createFileResource("WebContent/WEB-INF/flows/admin/flow-test.xml");
}

/**Register beans**/
@Override
protected void configureFlowBuilderContext(MockFlowBuilderContext builderContext)
{
    builderContext.registerBean("businessService", businessService);
    builderContext.registerBean("adminUserViewService", adminUserViewService);
}

/**Run Tests**/
@Test
public void testTestFlowEntryTest()
{
    try
    {
        TestSS.getLogger().debug("testTestFlowEntry ....");
        MutableAttributeMap input = new LocalAttributeMap();
        MockExternalContext econtext = new MockExternalContext();

        startFlow(input, econtext);

        assertCurrentStateEquals("hellotlv1");

        TestSS.getLogger().debug("testTestFlowEntry done");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        SS.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(), e);
        fail();

    }
}

@Test
public void testLoginSuccessTest()
{
    try
    {
    setCurrentState("xzlogin");
    MutableAttributeMap input = new LocalAttributeMap();
    ViewWrapperUserAdminLogin vwLogin = new ViewWrapperUserAdminLogin(new UserAdmin());
    vwLogin.setBusinessId(new Long(1));
    vwLogin.setUserName("jake0");
    vwLogin.setPassword("1234");
    vwLogin.setPin(1234);

    getFlowScope().put("userAdminForm", vwLogin);


    MockExternalContext context = new MockExternalContext();
    context.setEventId("dologin");
    resumeFlow(context);

    assertFlowExecutionEnded();
    assertFlowExecutionOutcomeEquals("xzhome");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        SS.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(),e);
        fail();
    }
}
```

}